# Bounded function with bounded second derivative imply bounded first derivative

Tags: real-analysis, derivatives, taylor-expansion

Let $f$ be a $C^2$ function from $(t_1,t_2)$ to $R^n$ such that $\Vert f(t)\Vert\leq A$ and $\Vert f''(t)\Vert \leq B$ for all $t\in (t_1,t_2)$, where $A$ and $B$ are nonnegative reals.

Let $t_0\in (t_1,t_2)$ and $\alpha>0$ be such that $(t_0-\alpha,t_0+\alpha)\subset (t_1,t_2)$.

I would like to prove that $\Vert f'(t_0)\Vert\leq 2A/\alpha + B\alpha/2$.

I thought of using a Taylor expansion of $f$ but cannot manage to get the inequality.

Comment: Are you sure about the inequality? I can obtain that the left hand side is smaller than $2A/\alpha+B\alpha/2.$

Comment: In my inequality there is a factor $2$ that multiplies the term $A/\alpha$

Answer (score 1):

First, it's enough to consider the case $n=1$: Say $v\in\Bbb R^n$ with $||v||=1$ and let $g(t)=f(t)\cdot v$. Then $|g'|\le A$ and $|g''(t)|\le B$; if we show that $|g'(t)|\le C$ then $|f'(t)\cdot v|\le C$ for all $v$ with $||v||=1$, hence $|f'(t)|\le C$.

Taylor's Theorem shows that for $t\in (t_0-\alpha,t_0+\alpha)$ we have $$f(t)=P(t)+R(t)$$where $$P(t)=f(t_0)+(t-t_0)f'(t_0)$$and $$|R(t)|\le\frac12 B(t-t_0)^2<\frac12 B\alpha^2.$$

So $$2A\ge|f(t)-f(t_0)|=|(t-t_0)f'(t_0)+R(t)|
\ge|t-t_0||f'(t_0)|-\frac12 B\alpha^2$$Chooing $t$ close to $t_0\pm\alpha$ now gives $$2A\ge\alpha|f'(t_0)|-\frac12B\alpha^2,$$or$$|f'(t_0)|\le2A/\alpha+\frac12 B\alpha.$$

Comment: I am not sure I understand how you restrict to $n=1$, since the hypothesis is on $f$ and not on $g$.

Comment: @filip We're given $||f||\le A$ and $||f''||\le B$. It _follows_ that $|g|\le A$ and $|g''|\le B$.

Comment: Yes but then how do you go back to the inequality on $f$ ? I agree that it is straight forward for the $L^1$ norm but what about the $L^2$ norm?

Comment: @filip If $|f'(t)\cdot v|\le C$ for every $v$ with $||v||=1$ then $||f'(t)||\le C$. (Let $v=f'(t)/||f'(t)||$.)

Comment: Something still bugs me. Suppose $n=2$. We have $\vert f'_i(t) \vert\leq C$ for $i=1,2$. Then we take the scalar product with $(\vert f'_1(t) \vert/\Vert f'(t) \Vert,\vert f'_2(t) \vert/\Vert f'(t) \Vert)$ we get $\Vert f'(t) \Vert\leq C((\vert f'_1(t) \vert+\vert f'_2(t) \vert)/\Vert f'(t) \Vert)$.

Comment: NO, you don't take thescalar product with $|f'|/||f'||$. That makes no sense, because that's not a vector. And we don't "have" what you said. We have $|f'\cdot v|\le C$ for every vector $v$ with $||v||=1$. Apply that with $v=f'/||f'||$. As I said. Recall that $x\cdot x=||x||^2$...

Comment: I think you read my comment too quickly. I suppose $n=2$ and I take the scalar product with a vector.

Comment: You want to take the scalar product with the vector $(f'_1/||f'||,f'_2/||f'||)$, not $(|f'_1|/||f'||,|f'_2|/||f'||)$. When you do that you don't get what you say.

Comment: Forget $f$ for a minute. We're simply applying the following standard fact: **Lemma** If $x\in\Bbb R^n$ then $||x||=\sup_{||v||=1}x\cdot v$.